# How to register fabric functions dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.6, fabric

**PROBLEM**

---

I'm trying to figure out how to wrap dynamically some of my fabric functions, in order to do I've created a little mcve snippet:

mcve_lib.py:

```
from fabric.api import run


def foo():
    run('hostname')
```

fabfile.py:

```
import sys
import mcve_lib

from fabric.api import settings, task, env, roles

env.roledefs = {
    'servers': ['foo_server']
}


def register_function(name, module, wrapped_func):

    @roles(['servers'])
    @task()
    def callback():
        with settings():
            getattr(module, wrapped_func)()

    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], name, callback)


register_function("wrapped_foo", mcve_lib, "foo")

print(dir())
```

Problem comes when i try to list the available fabric tasks by doing `fab -l`, the output will be this:

```
(py362_32) D:\sources\personal\python\framework\pyfab>fab -l
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'env', 'mcve_lib', 'register_function', 'roles', 'settings', 'sys', 'task', 'wrapped_foo']
Available commands:

    callback
```

**QUESTION**

---

Any idea how to indicate properly that `wrapped_foo` is a fabric task?

**FAILED ATTEMPTS**

---

Attempt1:

```
from fabric.tasks import WrappedCallableTask

...

def register_function(name, module, wrapped_func):

    @roles(['servers'])
    def callback():
        with settings():
            getattr(module, wrapped_func)()

    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], name, WrappedCallableTask(callback))

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to address this problem would be by using [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), usage example below:

```
import mcve_lib
import sys

from fabric.api import settings, task, env, roles
from functools import wraps

env.roledefs = {
    'servers': ['foo_server']
}


def register_function(f):

    @roles(['servers'])
    @task
    @wraps(f)
    def callback():
        with settings():
            f()

    return callback


module_funcs = [
    ('foo', mcve_lib.foo)
]

for dst_func, src_func in module_funcs:
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], dst_func, register_function(src_func))
```

By using the above code fabric will be able to enumerate properly the wrapped functions, ie:

```
(py362_32) D:\sources\personal\python\framework\pyfab>fab -l
Available commands:

    foo
```